# Python pandas obtain max consecutive times for a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` as below

| time | rate |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.0 |
| 1 | 0.7 |
| 2 | 0.5 |
| 3 | 0.4 |
| 5 | 0.2 |
| 6 | 0.1 |

I want to get the maximum consecutive 'time' of it. In this example that will be 4 ('0','1','2','3'; as we don't have a '4' as time)
How can I do it in Python / pandas ? Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected output - e.g., a frame, list, number, etc.?

Comment: A number would be good @It_is_Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case do `diff` with `cumsum`

```
df.time.diff().ne(1).cumsum().value_counts().max()
Out[132]: 4
```